# getting segmentation fault on a beaglebone black

Tags: c

im new to the beaglebone and linux so for a project im having to control the user led on the BBB by using the addresses as well as have a function for future use by ensuring all the gpio port are able to be set thru this. but when i run it to just turn on and off the user leds i get a segmentation fault and i don't know why or what i need to do to fix this. what do i need to include or is what i'm doing just a no go and if so what should i do?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    volatile uint32_t REVISION;         //Address offset: 0x00
    volatile uint32_t rangeA[3];        //Address offset: 0x04-0x0C
    volatile uint32_t SYSCONFIG;        //Address offset: 0x10
    volatile uint32_t rangeB[3];        //Address offset: 0x14-0x1C
    volatile uint32_t EOI;              //Address offset: 0x20
    volatile uint32_t IRQSTATUS_RAW_0;  //Address offset: 0x24
    volatile uint32_t IRQSTATUS_RAW_1;  //Address offset: 0x28
    volatile uint32_t IRQSTATUS_0;      //Address offset: 0x2C
    volatile uint32_t IRQSTATUS_1;      //Address offset: 0x30
    volatile uint32_t IRQSTATUS_SET_0;  //Address offset: 0x34
    volatile uint32_t IRQSTATUS_SET_1;  //Address offset: 0x38
    volatile uint32_t IRQSTATUS_CLR_0;  //Address offset: 0x3C
    volatile uint32_t IRQSTATUS_CLR_1;  //Address offset: 0x40
    volatile uint32_t IRQWAKEN_0 ;      //Address offset: 0x44
    volatile uint32_t IRQWAKEN_1;       //Address offset: 0x48
    volatile uint32_t rangeC[26];       //Address offset: 0x4C-0x110
    volatile uint32_t SYSSTATUS;        //Address offset: 0x114
    volatile uint32_t rangeD[6];        //Address offset: 0x118-0x12C
    volatile uint32_t CTRL;             //Address offset: 0x130
    volatile uint32_t OE;               //Address offset: 0x134
    volatile uint32_t DATAIN;           //Address offset: 0x138
    volatile uint32_t DATAOUT;          //Address offset: 0x13C
    volatile uint32_t LEVELDETECT0;     //Address offset: 0x140
    volatile uint32_t LEVELDETECT1;     //Address offset: 0x144
    volatile uint32_t RISINGDETEDT;     //Address offset: 0x148
    volatile uint32_t FALLINGDETECT;    //Address offset: 0x14C
    volatile uint32_t DEBOUNCENABLE;    //Address offset: 0x150
    volatile uint32_t DEBOUNCINGTIME;   //Address offset: 0x154
    volatile uint32_t rangeE[14];       //Address offset: 0x158-0x18C
    volatile uint32_t CLEARDATAOUT;     //Address offset: 0x190
    volatile uint32_t SETDATAOUT;       //Address offset: 0x194
} GPIO_TypeDef;

#define GPIO0 ((GPIO_TypeDef *) 0x44E07000)
#define GPIO1 ((GPIO_TypeDef *) 0x4804C000)
#define GPIO2 ((GPIO_TypeDef *) 0x481AC000)
#define GPIO3 ((GPIO_TypeDef *) 0x481AE000)

int main()      //testing if this would work
{
    GPIO1->OE &= ~(1UL<<21);       // set  bits to output eneble
    while(1)
    {
        GPIO1->DATAOUT |= 1UL<<21;
        int delay = 0;
        while(delay < 15000)    // just really quick crappy delay
            delay++;
        GPIO1->DATAOUT &= ~(1UL<<21);
        printf("Blink!!\n");    //test to see if it works
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some punctuation and capitalisation to your prose. (Downvote not by me though.)

Comment: I don't know anything about beagleboards, but how is your code supposed to get out of the while(1) loop? What line is your seg fault on?

Comment: i just ctrl c to end the program as this was mainly a test to see if i could get it to write to the address as i intend to. it was just meant to blink the led and the second it runs it gives me the fault.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code presented .. you sure the `struct` and memory addresses are defined correctly?

Comment: i followed the addresses and according offset provided by the processors(AM335x 1GHz ARM® Cortex-A8) reference manual will triple check if made a mistake in the addresses.

Comment: Are you running it in a process that has appropriate permissions?

Comment: this a new BBB out of box with pre-installed linux. i've been doing my programs in root and haven't messed with the permission. since root has the highest permissions..? i know it comes with a driver that can control the port but for my project i need to go higher level and work with the actual addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The addresses that you have assigned appear to be physical or bus addresses; your program will run with virtual or program addresses.   The kernel on your machine constructs translation pages so your program can keep a normalized view of memory addresses which the kernel can assign dynamically.

You need to map (using mmap()) the device space of the registers into your program, and assign your structure to point to them.

You should end up with code that looks something like:

```
GPIO_TypeDef  *g0, *g1, ... ;
...
g0 = mmap(0, sizeof *g0,..., fd, 0);
...
g0->DataOut = 3;
...
```

ps: stylistically, prepending _TypeDef defeats the purpose of the typedef mechanism, which is to make meaningful names and self documenting programs.   The idio(ma)?tic use of _t is only a bit better because it doesn’t waste so many keystrokes.   Remember that some programmers are visually impaired, and have to listen to an assistive device say “underscore uppercase T y p e uppercase D e f” each time they encounter that!